# Apache URL rewrite trick to fix encoded "http://"

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

I've some leading to a site that end up poorly formated like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/directory/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.another.com%2Falink-that-doesnt-work
```

I would like a rewrite rule to truncate that part until the url and fix the encoding to redirect to

```
http://www.another.com/alink-that-doesnt-work
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extract the hostname and link from the URL using a regular expression and used back references to substitute and redirect. Note that patterns are matched against decoded URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   /directory/http://([^/]*)/(.*)    http://$1/$2   [R]
```